# jquery click input[type=''] doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with .click() event in jquery. I create an input tag with a button, and then when I click this tag it must show an alert message. But it doesn't work. 
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="test">

</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```

And the Jquery code:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){    
    html = "<input type='text' size='1' name='courses[]' value='1' />";
    $("#test").after(html);
});
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function(){             
    alert('ppp');

});
```

All libraries of jquery are linked in the real site.
Here is an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82pps6Lz/29/
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use delegated binding -- [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on). The `<input>` doesn't yet exist when `$("input[type='text']")` would be trying to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).on("click","input[type='text']", function(){             
    alert('ppp');
});
```

The above is how you use event-delegation. You can also bind after `<input>` exists.

#### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/82pps6Lz/31/)

Answer (score 7):

Think, you insert a new `<input>` element only when you click on the button, but you bind a `click` event straight away, when the `<input>` element doesn't yet exist. So you either should bind the event after (or during) element insertion:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){    
    var html = "<input type='text' size='1' name='courses[]' value='1' />";
    $(html).on('click', function() {
        // ...
    }).insertAfter('#test');
});
```

... or use the [DOM event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){    
    var html = "<input type='text' size='1' name='courses[]' value='1' />";
    $('#test').after(html);
});

$(document).on('click', 'input[type="text"]' function() {             
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the input after insertion. because when you perform `$("input[type='text']")` the `input` not exists. it exists until you click on `submit`.

```
      $("#btn").click(function(){    
           html = "<input type='text' size='1' name='courses[]' value='1' />";
           $("#test").after(html);
           $("input[type='text']").on("click", function(){             
                 alert('ppp');

           });
       });
```

Comment: Remember to always comment your code when you answer, code-only answers are low quality.

Comment: @Nit yes, I was editing it.

Comment: @Nit At least he was the first to answer... `:)`

Comment: Being first to answer doesn't offer much unless the answer offers any useful input.